# If $P$ denotes the Cantor set, then show that $[0, 1] \setminus P$ is dense in $[0, 1]$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have done the following. Suggest if the Proof is rigorous enough.

Let us select any point $x\in [0,1]$. Ternary expansion of $x$ can be represented by $x=0.b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4\ldots$ where $b_i=0,1\text{ or }2$.

So, any $x\in [0,1]$ either lies in Cantor Set $P$ or does not lie in $P$.

Case 1: $x\notin P$

then $x\in \{[0,1]\setminus P\}\subset [0,1]$

So, $\forall r>0, B_{r}(x)$ contains an element of $[0,1]\setminus P$ since $B_{r}(x)$ contains at least $x$.

Case 2:  $x\in P$

Then $x$ has a ternary expansion $x=0.b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}b_{4}\ldots$ where $b_{i}=0\text{ or }2$.
Appending a $1$ far enough down the expansion of $x$, we get $x^{'}\in \{[0,1]\setminus P\}\subset [0,1]$. Also, $x^{'}$ is arbitrarily close to $x$.  So, $\forall r>0, B_{r}(x)$ contains $x^{'}$ which is an element of $[0,1]\setminus P$.

So, $ [0, 1] \setminus P$  is dense in $[0, 1]$.

Is Case 2 rigorous enough?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation should help you fix this. note that a backslash is `\setminus`, the character $\setminus$ is reserved.

Comment: Use 'setminus' to display the sign for the difference of sets.

Comment: @AlexR and ajotatxe: Ok.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cantor sets in ternary use only 0 or 2 (instead of 1)
2. you cannot "append" a 1 further enough, since the ternary expansion may require infinitely many "2" (e.g. 0.2222222$\cdots$).

To prove $[0,1]\backslash P$ is dense in $[0,1]$, just note that $P$ has empty interior since its Lebesgue measure is 0.

Comment: @Brian: Can you please suggest a proof then?

Comment: @Brian: Are you suggesting I have done the correct proof?

Comment: @Martin: Not quite, but your idea is salvageable: see my answer.

Comment: @Milly: It was a typo that I wrote 1 instead of 2 for teranary expansion in $P$

Comment: yeah, OP's case 1 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It isn’t really necessary to consider the case $x\notin P$, since any open nbhd of such a point obviously meets $[0,1]\setminus P$, but there’s no real harm in it. As noted in Milly’s answer, there are a couple of problems with your argument in the essential case in which $x\in P$. That implies that $x$ has a ternary expansion $0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots$ in which each $b_k$ is either $0$ or $2$. Changing some $b_k$ to a $1$ doesn’t quite guarantee that the new number isn’t in $P$: if $b_i=2$ for all $i>k$, then you get

$$0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}1222\ldots=0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}2000\ldots\;,$$

which is in $P$. However, you can change a whole tail of digits to $1$s:

$$0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}111\ldots$$

cannot be in $P$.

It only remains to show that if you take $k$ large enough, you can make

$$|0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}b_kb_{k+1}\ldots-0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}111\ldots|$$

arbitrarily small. You might note that $x$ lies between $0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}$ and $0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}222\ldots$ inclusive; this allows you to express the maximum possible distance between $x$ and the new number in terms of $k$.

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the part: $x$ lies between $0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}$ and $0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}222\ldots$ inclusive; this allows you to express the maximum possible distance between $x$ and the new number in terms of $k$

Comment: @Martin: The first of those is the smallest number whose ternary expansion begins $0.b_1\ldots b_{k-1}$, and the second is the smallest, so any such number must lie between them. What do you get when you subtract the first from the new number? The new number from the second? Those put a limit on how far your new number can be from $x$.